# Как отлаживать код на React.js при его использовании без Node.js?

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, maven

Взял пример проекта https://github.com/emmostrom/JavaReact, в котором есть jsx код. Всё собирается через maven + frontend-maven-plugin (который запускает webpack для сборки клиентского кода).

Запускаю под Tomcat, всё хорошо работает.

Но как отлаживать клиентский код? В chrome dev tools минифицированный код, и никакого jsx там нету.

Comment: React devtools, sourcemaps

Answer (score 0):

Приветствую!

Конфига вебпака имеет параметр "devtool" (таблица значений https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)

В вашем проекте видим в webpack.config.js

```
var production = process.argv.reduce(function(p, c){return p || c == '-p'}, false)
devtool: production ? 'cheap-source-map' : 'source-map',
```

Таким образом если запускать проект без флага `-p` сорсмапы должны поступать в браузер и появляться в chrome dev tools

Не работает?